# strptime with 3 character timezone and AM/PM

Tags: python, strptime

Based on the documentation for `strptime`, I believe my code is correct for a 3 character timezone and AM/PM.

Why does Python 2.5 and Python 3.6 not like the string time format I am using?

```
import datetime
ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "11/30/2017 01:08:05 PM CST", 
    '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %z'
)
```

or

```
import datetime
ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "11/30/2017 01:08:05 PM CST", 
    '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z'
)
```

When run both return:

```
ValueError: time data '11/30/2017 01:08:05 PM CST' does 
not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z'
```

Comment: Whoops, not sure how that % got deleted, but I am getting the same error with the %S in there too.  I'll edit the original post

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime("11/30/2017 01:08:05 PM", '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')` works. Hm...

Comment: Yes, but how do I take the timezone into account?

Comment: I did some googling.. looks like there is a problem with CST: See this for instance: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbolic timezones such as `CST` are not parsed by `strptime`.  Furthery they are relatively meaningless.  Is `CST`:

- Central Standard Time; or
- China Standard Time; or
- Cuba Standard Time.

To handle your situation you should consider using `dateutil.parser`, and giving it a `tzinfo` for the timezones you wish to support.