# Parsing datestring in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following datestring:

```
d = 'Fri Nov 20, 7:54AM CST'
```

That i am trying to parse using the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strptime(d, '%a %b %d, %I:%M%p %Z')
```

I receive the following error: `ValueError: time data 'Fri Nov 20, 7:54AM CST' does not match format '%a %b %d, %I:%M%p %Z'`

I don't understand what i am doing wrong, can anyone help ?

Comment: `20` is the day number of month, or year ?

Comment: day of the month.. but you are right it is missing the year...

Comment: Also all python type for format, are zero-padded, so you can't parse `7`, only `07`

Comment: this is data i am collecting from outside source, how would you go at parsing it nevertheless ?

Comment: It has to be the CST if you cut that off it works - although it would fall back to 1900 `datetime.datetime.strptime(d[:-4], '%a %b %d, %I:%M%p')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877346/strptime-with-3-character-timezone-and-am-pm

Comment: @azro Non zero-padded times are fine, see: `dt.strptime("7:54", "%I:%M")`

Comment: thx alex for the pointer

Comment: Did a little bit more digging: https://bugs.python.org/issue22377 there aren't many timezone names. [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) maybe the way

Comment: the `CST` [time zone name abbreviation](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) is ambiguous, so it is sane to raise an exception if you try to parse it with %Z. You can remove the ambiguity by a time zone mapping as @butterflyknife shows in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65233712/10197418).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help? It's a bit unclear what you want to do with the timezone, so I've shown two options (ignore or not).

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.tz import gettz

d = 'Fri Nov 19, 7:54AM CST'

print(parse(d)) // 2020-11-19 07:54:00

tzinfos = {"CST": gettz("America/Chicago")}
print(parse(d, tzinfos=tzinfos)) // 2020-11-19 07:54:00-06:00
```

Also you haven't specified how you want to set the year; the default is to use the current year (I changed your example to the 19th of November to make this clear).

EDIT: to answer your actual question, your code doesn't work because (a) `%I` expects a zero-padded decimal number (actually, see Edit 2), and (b) `%Z` only accepts empty, `'UTC'` or `'GMT'`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

EDIT 2: Digging a bit deeper, the following works (changed CST to GMT to make it work):

```
d = 'Fri Nov 19, 7:54AM GMT'
print(dt.strptime(d, '%a %b %d, %I:%M%p %Z')) // 1900-11-19 07:54:00
                                              // Note the year is now 1900.
```

So it appears that `'%I'` doesn't in fact require a zero-padded number, in contradiction to the linked page above. Don't know what's going on there.

Comment: `%Z` parses other abbreviations than UTC and GMT on some systems; still, it is better to explicitly map the abbreviation to a time zone as you show (see also my comment on the question).